# Define scopes using the portal not cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When following tutorials using the CLI or using the setup Wizard in DevOps roles are added to give certain services permission to interact and a scope is set.

When I go to manually add a role assignment in IAM access control (This is for an Azure Container Registry) then I don't see any option in the GUI to define scopes.

Is this something that has to be done via the CLI?

Comment: Any more questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the role in the Azure portal for one exact resource in the IAM blade, it means the scope is already a certain one: the resource that you select. For you, the scope is the Azure Container Registry. And you just need to select the role and who would access the ACR with the role.